# Bulk regex removals against large array very slow in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to find the quickest / most efficient way to run many regex removals against an array.

My `$hosts` array contains tens of thousands of individual items, in domain format. E.g:

- test.domain.xyz
- domain.xyz
- something.com
- anotherdomain.net

My `$local_regex` array contains ~1000 indivdual regexes, in multi-line format. E.g:

- ^ad. (ad.*)
- domain.xyz$ (*domain.xyz)

I am currently trying to exclude any regex matches in the following way, but it is EXTREMELY slow with a large array and many regexes to match:

```
Function Regex-Remove
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $local_regex,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $hosts
    )

    # Loop through each regex and select only non-matching items
    foreach($regex in $local_regex)
    {
        # Multi line, case insensitive
        $regex = "(?im)$regex"

        # Select hosts that do not match regex
        $hosts = $hosts -notmatch $regex
    }

    return $hosts
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `$regex = '(?im)' + ($local_regex -join '|')`

Comment: There are too many regexes to do this - It errors out unfortunately.

Comment: You may want to consider consolidating your regular expressions first. 1000 regular expressions (multiline on top of that) is insane.

Comment: Just wondering how many truly unique regexes you have as well. Are you sure none of them could be consolidated?

Comment: This is purely for testing at the moment. My actual regex list is ~ 20 entries. 

I am trying to replicate filter list behaviour with knox firewall, which basically means that I need the domain from the filter list, and the wildcard: something.com, *.something.com. Prefixing as *something.com has proven too restrictive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Roberto, I switched the `$hosts` array to a `New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`

The ability to remove from the ArrayList on the fly is exactly what I needed, and the while loop makes sure to remove duplicate values.

```
Function Regex-Remove
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $local_regex,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $hosts
    )

    # Loop through each regex and select only non-matching items
    foreach($regex in $local_regex)
    {
        # Multi line, case insensitive
        $regex = "(?i)$regex"

        # Select hosts that do not match regex
        $hosts -match $regex | % {
            while($hosts.Contains($_))
            {
                $hosts.Remove($_)
            }
        }
    }

    return $hosts
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reassigning a large array is going to be costly. Changing an array's size requires allocating a new array and copying the contents into it. If you have, say, 10 000 hostnames and 1 000 regexes, you have 10 000 000 copy operations. That's going to have some measurable effect. There is a cmdlet `Measure-Command` which is used to time execution times.

As an alternative approach, try to use indexed an array and overwrite undesired values with `$null` values. Like so,

```
foreach($regex in $local_regex) {
    $regex = "(?im)$regex"
    for($i=0;$i -lt $hosts.length; ++$i) {
        if( $hosts[$i] -match $regex) {
            $hosts[$i] = $null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An ArrayList is also much faster than resizing arrays.

Comment: Ah, I had wondered whether creating new arrays for this was costly. Although I am sure that this would finish quicker, It's still looking at every single host thousands of times (depending on the size of the regex array).

Would it be any quicker if I looked to add all hosts to a string instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Collections.ArrayList objects instead of arrays, this will make the process much faster, and you have methods to add / remove items without rebuilding the whole array

```
$var = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$var.Add()
$var.AddRange()
$var.Remove()
$var.RemoveRange()
```